# Showing that $|g(x)| \leq M$

Tags: real-analysis

I was working on the following problem

> Let $\{g_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$. Assume that there is a number $M$ such that $|g_{k}(x)| \leq M$ for every $k$ and every $x \in [0,1]$ and also there is a continuous real-valued function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that 
>   $$ \int^{1}_{0} g_{k}(x)p(x)dx \to \int^{1}_{0} g(x)p(x)dx$$
>   as $k \to \infty$ for every polynomial $p$. Prove that $|g(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ and that
>   $$ \int^{1}_{0} g_{k}(x)f(x)dx \to \int^{1}_{0} g(x)f(x)dx$$ for every continuous $f$.

**I am having trouble showing $|g(x)| \leq M$**

I was able to show that $ \int^{1}_{0} g_{k}(x)f(x)dx \to \int^{1}_{0} g(x)f(x)dx$ assuming that $|g(x)| \leq M$. I did this by estimating
$$E= \vert \int^{1}_{0} g_{n}(x)f(x)dx- \int^{1}_{0} g(x)f(x)dx \vert$$. We then have by the triangle inequality that 
$$
E \leq E_{1}+ E_{2}
$$
where 
\begin{align*}
E_{1} &=  \vert \int^{1}_{0} g_{n}(x)p_{k}(x)dx - \int^{1}_{0} g_{n}(x)f(x)dx \vert \\
E_{2} &= \vert  \int^{1}_{0} g_{n}(x)f(x)dx-\int^{1}_{0} g(x)f(x)dx \vert \\
\end{align*}

I can make $E_{1}$ "small" using the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, but to make $E_{2}$ "small", I needed to assume that $|g(x)| \leq M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow how you split things into two terms. Seems to me the natural thing is
$$|\int g_nf-\int gf|\le|\int g_nf-\int g_np_k|+|\int g_np_k-\int gp_k|+|\int gp_k-\int gf|=E_1+E_2+E_3.$$

Now. You're given that $g$ is continuous. So there exists $N$ such that $|g|\le N$. This works just as well as if you already knew $|g|\le M$. Suppose $p_k\to f$ uniformly. If $k$ is large enough then $E_1<\epsilon$ for *all* $n$ and if $k$ is large enough then $E_3<\epsilon$ for *all* $n$. Now fix $k$ "large enough" that both those conditions are satisfied; if $n$ is large enough then $E_2<\epsilon$.

So that gives a proof that $\int g_nf\to\int gf$ for every continuous $f$.

This implies that $|\int gf|\le M \int|f|$ for  every continuous $f$. And it follows from that (leaving something for you) that $|g|\le M$.

Comment: Thanks, the $E_{2}$ that I wrote above  I think actually splits into the $E_{2}$ and $E_{3}$ that you wrote, I was too lazy to write it there. I forgot to notice that $g$ was continuous on a compact set. I can complete the estimate I had. I can see why $|\int gf | \leq M \int |f|$ by taking $f=1$. But is there a way to see rigorously,  how $\int g_{n} f \to \int gf$ implies that $| \int gf | \leq M \int |f|$?

Comment: (1) If you say so - I cannot see how your error is smaller than your $E_1+E_2$, simply doesn't add up as far as I can see. (2) If $|a_n|\le 1$ and $a_n\to a$ then $|a|\le 1$.